# BroadCast Receiver calling intent not working for second time

Tags: android, android-intent

In my i have a receiver to predict incoming calls,Once i have the call i need bring my app to front of screen(Over call accept and reject scree), the code for receiver is shown below,

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if(null == bundle)
            return;

        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {
            String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);

            String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;

            Intent intent2open = new Intent(context, com.varma.samples.detectcalls.ui.MainActivity.class);
            intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent2open.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            String name = "KEY";
            String value = "String you want to pass";
            intent2open.putExtra(name, value);
            context.startActivity(intent2open);
            Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

in my manifest i added following parameters,

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.varma.samples.detectcalls.ui.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:taskAffinity="@android:string/no">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.varma.samples.detectcalls.receivers.OutgoingCallReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.varma.samples.detectcalls.receivers.IncomingCallReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

But when i launch the activity the receiver is started to listen incoming calls,then i close all instance of app in Settings, when call is coming for first time, my app is bring front over answer & reject screen.

Then i push back button to reject my call. Then when i make a call again the activity was not bring in front of my dialing screen. I don`t know where is the problem.

Comment: tried putting android:priority="100 to your intent-filter tag in manifest?

Comment: log a message for `if(null == bundle) return;`

Comment: did you find the solution? if yes please help me